# How does 'Collections.sort()' use the result of the 'compare()' method?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, compare, comparator

The output of the compare() method in the Comparator interface is either -1,0, or 1. This then gets passed to the Collections.sort() method which can be used to sort a list in a custom way.

What does sort() do with the result of the compare() method though? (the -1,0 or 1)

I think what I am most confused about is that there are three outputs of compare()
negative, positive or 0). But why don't the algorithms only need two of these? Can't the
action when a=b be the same as when a>b or when a<b? and so don't we only really need two outputs? (ei. positive and negative)

eg. comparing two numbers a and b, if a<b or a=b then take the a (eg. compare() returns -1), and if a>b then take b (compare() return +1). Why does the algorithm need to differentiate between a<b and a=b?

eg.

```
class ReverseAlphabeticalComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

@Override
public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
    if(i1 > i2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(i1 < i2) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}  

class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> animals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    animals.add(6);
    animals.add(2);
    animals.add(4);
    animals.add(7);
    animals.add(8);
    animals.add(3);

    Collections.sort(numbers, new ReverseNumericalComparator());

        for(String numbers: numbers) {
            System.out.println(numbers); //Prints numbers in reverse eg. 8,7,6,4,3,2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you try working out how you would write a sorting algorithm for a list of element using nothing but a method which tells you if two objects are greater than, less than or equal to each other, then you can answer your own question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> What does sort() do with the result of the compare() method though?

`sort` compares series of pairs of elements and based on result of `compare` it sees if elements from that pair should be swapped or not.

Also result of `compare` doesn't have to be `-1` `0` and `1`. From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-)

> Returns a `negative` integer, `zero`, or a `positive` integer as the first argument is
>     *less than*, *equal to*, or *greater than* the second.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what it does (Collections.sort calls Arrays.sort which calls Arrays.mergeSort) :

```
private static void mergeSort(Object[] src,
                              Object[] dest,
                              int low, int high, int off,
                              Comparator c) {

    int length = high - low;

    // Insertion sort on smallest arrays
    if (length < INSERTIONSORT_THRESHOLD) {
        for (int i=low; i<high; i++)
            for (int j=i; j>low && c.compare(dest[j-1], dest[j])>0; j--)
                swap(dest, j, j-1);
        return;
    }

    // Recursively sort halves of dest into src
    int destLow  = low;
    int destHigh = high;
    low  += off;
    high += off;
    int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;

    mergeSort(dest, src, low, mid, -off, c);
    mergeSort(dest, src, mid, high, -off, c);

    // If list is already sorted, just copy from src to dest.  This is an
    // optimization that results in faster sorts for nearly ordered lists.
    if (c.compare(src[mid-1], src[mid]) <= 0) {
       System.arraycopy(src, low, dest, destLow, length);
       return;
    }

    // Merge sorted halves (now in src) into dest
    for(int i = destLow, p = low, q = mid; i < destHigh; i++) {
        if (q >= high || p < mid && c.compare(src[p], src[q]) <= 0)
            dest[i] = src[p++];
        else
            dest[i] = src[q++];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the recent implementations use timsort instead of standard mergesort. Edit: Ah, Java 7 uses timsort for non-primitive sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Most (all?) sorting algorithms need to know only whether `a` is smaller/bigger/equal to `b` for each element in the set that we are sorting. Therefore you only need to return a negative, 0, or positive (in many cases -1, 0, and 1) value from `compare()`.

If you read about different sorting algorithms, you'll notice that they're built on this, from the simple bubble sort to quicksort, mergesort and others.

Comment: Comparison algorithms are a proper subset of all sorting algorithms. They have a provable minimum asymptotic complexity of nlogn. There are other non-comparison sorting algorithms that have better asymptotic complexities, such as counting sort. However, these faster-than-nlogn non-comparison algorithms have caveats, such as requiring you to know the distribution of your data (bucket sort) or scaling linearly in complexity with the number of digits in your data (radix sort). We use comparison sorting because it doesn't have these issues and nlogn in almost as good as n in many cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have editing my question to explain more fully what I am confused about